# how count and plot several searches at once?

Tags: splunk

I am counting the number of hits on my website using `splunk`. My current search looks for a `keywordA`  as follows:

```
index=mydata keywordA |bucket _time span=day |stats count by _time
```

However, I would like to add several other searches to the output, say for other keywords (`keywordB` for instance):

```
index=mydata keywordB |bucket _time span=day |stats count by _time
```

Note: these searches are not necessarily mutually exlusive! So the searches need to be run independently.

I would like to have the **total daily count** for each search at once, so that I avoid running each search separately.

Output should be:

```
day          keyA  keyB
2020-01-01   423   354
2020-01-02   523   254
```

What is the best way to proceed?

Thanks!

Comment: is this "keyword" in a named field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this search that combines your two.  Other than the stats command, it doesn't scale well for many keywords.

```
index=mydata (keywordA OR keywordB)
| bin span=1d _time
| eval keyword = case(match(_raw, "keywordA"), "keywordA", match(_raw, "keywordB"), "keywordB", 1==1, "other")
| stats count by _time, keyword
```

Comment: thanks!! but I need to group by day, not by time. What do you mean it does not scale well?

Comment: I updated my answer to group events by day.  By scaling, I mean for each additional keyword you want to find you need to update the query in two places.

Comment: thanks but that would not work well if both A and B are in the same record, right? what is the grouping doing in that case?

Comment: Correct.  If A and B are both in the same record then only A will be counted and used for grouping.